# Nesting custom taglibs in grails 2.0

Tags: grails, nested, taglib, grails-2.0

I expected the following to ouput `1 2`

**GSP**

```
<test:test1>
    <test:test2>
        ${test1} ${test2}
    </test:test2>
</test:test1>
```

**TagLib**

```
class TestTagLib {

    static namespace = "test"

    def test1 = { attrs, body ->
        out << body(test1:1)        
    }

    def test2 = { attrs, body ->
        out << body(test2:2)
    }
}
```

Instead it results in `1`, meaning that the inner variables are not correctly resolved. Is it a grails 2.0 bug? Is there any workaround?

Comment: It sure looks like a bug.  I've been trying to track it down, but so far all I can do is confirm that the inner taglib's properties are ignored, but only if the outer taglib sets properties on the body.

Comment: Also, it appears that Grails 2.0 doesn't reload taglib changes without completely exiting grails (interactive mode or run-app) and restarting it, making testing a real pain.

Comment: Regarding restarting of the server: I guess its a problem of the IDE. I use STS and facing the same issue as you described. I guess we should raise a ticket against STS :-)

Comment: In this case, I was using the interactive command line directly.  I don't use STS. I use IntelliJ normally, but haven't upgraded to 11 yet, so my grails 2.0 testing tends to be rather manual... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug and will be fixed in 2.0.1.

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8554